# Help with missing border in latex table

Tags: tables

I am having trouble with generating a proper latex table.
I am currently using the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Application and Activity Name                                                                & Original \textbackslash Faulted & Activity Classified as:          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Functional Bugs Discovered}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}K-9Mail:\\ MessageList\end{tabular}}              & Original                        & \multirow{5}{*}{Mail Activity}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1 bug has been found:\\ \# Sending an email with invalid\\             recipient address - Failed\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} 
                                                                                             & \multirow{5}{*}{Faulted}        &                                  & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4 bugs have been found:\\ \# Opening an email from the inbox\\    mails list - Failed\\ \# Sending an email without\\    recipient address - Failed\\ \# Sending an email with invalid\\    recipient address - Failed\\ \# Sending and receiving a valid\\    mail - Failed\end{tabular}} \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \hline 
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}K-9Mail:\\ setup.AccountSetupBasics\end{tabular}} & Original                        & \multirow{6}{*}{Login Activity}  & No bugs have been found                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} 
                                                                                             & \multirow{5}{*}{Faulted}        &                                  & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3 bugs have been found:\\ \# Login without username and\\    password - Failed\\ \# Login with wrong username\\    and password - Failed\\ \# Login with valid username\\    and password - Failed\end{tabular}}                                                                           \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \\ \\ \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}CrimeTalk:\\ MainActivity\end{tabular}}           & Original                        & \multirow{6}{*}{Portal Activity} & No bugs have been found                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} 
                                                                                             & \multirow{5}{*}{Faulted}        &                                  & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3 bugs have been found:\\ \# Browsing through the portal's\\    sections by swiping it left \\    and right - Failed\\ \# Switching between the portal's\\    tabs - Failed\\ \# Opening an article - Failed\end{tabular}}                                                                 \\ 
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\
                                                                                             &                                 &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \\ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, the table which I am getting is this one:
[image]

As can be seen, this table has missing border in some of its places.
Can someone please correct my code to fix this problem?
I have tried hours to solve it without any luck.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Orel.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that operates with a dedicated, compact itemize-like environment for the items in the fourth column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Setup a compact ittemize-like env.
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\#,
                 nosep, wide, leftmargin=*,
                 before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.85\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|Y|}
\hline
Application and Activity Name                                                                & Original\slash Faulted 
& Activity Classified as:
& Functional Bugs Discovered \\ 
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
    K-9Mail:\\ 
    MessageList
    \end{tabular}}
& Original
& \multirow{5}{*}{Mail Activity}   
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}Y@{}}
  1 bug was found:\\
  \begin{mylist}
  \item Sending an email with invalid recipient address~-- Failed
  \end{mylist}
\end{tabular} \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} 
& \multirow{5}{*}{Faulted} 
&
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}Y@{}}
  4 bugs were found:\\
  \begin{mylist}
  \item Opening an email from the inbox mails list~-- Failed
  \item Sending an email without recipient address~-- Failed
  \item Sending an email with invalid recipient address~-- Failed
  \item Sending and receiving a valid mail~-- Failed
  \end{mylist}
\end{tabular} \\ 
\hline 
\multirow{6}{*}{%
   \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
   K-9Mail:\\ 
   setup.AccountSetupBasics
   \end{tabular}} 
& Original
& \multirow{6}{*}{Login Activity}  
& No bugs were found                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
& \multirow{5}{*}{Faulted}
&
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}Y@{}}
  3 bugs were found:\\ 
  \begin{mylist}
  \item Login without username and password~-- Failed
  \item Login with wrong username and password~-- Failed
  \item Login with valid username and password~-- Failed
  \end{mylist}
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
    CrimeTalk:\\ 
    MainActivity
    \end{tabular}}
& Original
& \multirow{6}{*}{Portal Activity} 
& No bugs were found                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
& \multirow{5}{*}{Faulted}
&
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}Y@{}}
  3 bugs were found:\\
  \begin{mylist}
  \item Browsing through the portal's sections by swiping it left and right~-- Failed
  \item Switching between the portal's tabs~-- Failed
  \item Opening an article~-- Failed
  \end{mylist}
\end{tabular} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The missing lines seem to be caused by your usage of `\multirow` in combination with all the empty rows. A corrected code of the first third of your table would be the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Application and Activity Name                                                                & Original \textbackslash Faulted & Activity Classified as:          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Functional Bugs Discovered}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}K-9Mail:\\ MessageList\end{tabular} }             & Original                        & \multirow{10}{*}{Mail Activity}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1 bug has been found:\\ \# Sending an email with invalid\\             recipient address - Failed\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} 
                                                                                             & \multirow{2}{*}{Faulted}        &                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4 bugs have been found:\\ \# Opening an email from the inbox\\    mails list - Failed\\ \# Sending an email without\\    recipient address - Failed\\ \# Sending an email with invalid\\    recipient address - Failed\\ \# Sending and receiving a valid\\    mail - Failed\end{tabular} \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nevertheless, the table still does not fit onto a portrait page and looks somewhat cramped due to all the vertical and horizontal lines. A redesign could look like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L{2.5cm}L{2cm}L{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
Application and Activity Name   & Activity Classified as:   & Original \textbackslash Faulted & Functional Bugs Discovered \\
\midrule
K-9Mail: \newline MessageList  &  Mail \newline Activity   &Original  & 1 bug has been found:\newline \# Sending an email with invalid recipient address - Failed \\
\cmidrule{3-4}
 &  & Faulted   & 4 bugs have been found:\newline \# Opening an email from the inbox mails list - Failed\newline  \# Sending an email without recipient address - Failed\newline  \# Sending an email with invalid recipient address - Failed\newline  \# Sending and receiving a valid mail - Failed \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does look better. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, also based on `tabularx` and `enumitem`, with no nested `tabular`, but using `makecell` instead, since it allows for linebreaks in standard cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\#, noitemsep, topsep=2pt, wide=0pt, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c| >{\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\makecell{Application and\\ Activity Name} & \makecell{Original\\ \textbackslash Faulted} & \makecell{Activity\\ Classified as:} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Functional Bugs Discovered} \\
\hline
\multirowcell{11}{K-9Mail:\\ MessageList} & Original & \multirowcell{11}{Mail Activity} & 1 bug has been found:\begin{tabitemize}\item Sending an email with invalid recipient address – Failed \end{tabitemize}\\
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 & \multirowcell{5}{Faulted} &
 & 4 bugs have been found:\begin{tabitemize}
 \item Opening an email from the inbox mails list – Failed
 \item Sending an email without recipient address – Failed
 \item Sending an email with invalid recipient address – Failed
 \item Sending and receiving a valid mail – Failed
\end{tabitemize}
 \\ \hline
\multirowcell{7.5}{K-9Mail:\\ setup.AccountSetupBasics} & Original & \multirowcell{7.5}{Login Activity} & No bugs have been found \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 & \multirowcell{5.5}{Faulted} & & 3 bugs have been found: \begin{tabitemize}
 \item Login without username and password – Failed
 \item Login with wrong username and password – Failed
 \item Login with valid username and password – Failed
 \end{tabitemize}
\\ \hline
\multirowcell{7.5}{CrimeTalk:\\ MainActivity} & Original & \multirowcell{7.5}{Portal Activity} & No bugs have been found \\
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
 & \multirowcell{5.5}{Faulted} & & 3 bugs have been found: \begin{tabitemize}
 \item Browsing through the portal's sections by swiping it left and right – Failed
 \item Switching between the portal's tabs – Failed
 \item Opening an article – Failed
 \end{tabitemize}
 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding another upvote.+1.